# I have a problem with the parameters in fastapi

Tags: python, html, web, parameter-passing, fastapi

I have this application in fastapi. through a get request the page and area2 parameters are passed, the page parameter is correctly captured but the area2 is not, it returns none

```
@router.get("/")
async def home(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db), page:int= 1, area2: str=None):
  print(page, area2)
  ...
```

This is my html

```
<span class="step-links"  >
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1?&area2={{area}}">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.number-1}}&?area={{area}}">  --previous  </a>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Did you notice that the "previous" button has the key as "area" instead of "area2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is only necessary to put a single "?" for variables**

```
 <span class="step-links"  >
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1?area2={{area}}">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.number-1}}?area={{area}}">  --previous  </a>
    {% endif %}
```